# Displaying Arrays with MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, discord, discord.js

Hello StackOverflow people, I require assistance with my Discord bot and my MongoDB database.
I've created a schema that has an argument, I guess that is an array.
When I find the Schema for my Discord server and try to log the array to the console it sends undefined.

```
import ConfigSchema from "../../schemas/config.ts";

const configFiles = await ConfigSchema.findOne({
    guildID: message.guild?.id
}).exec();

console.log(configFiles.adminRoleID)
//Should have [ "Test" ] in it, but displays undefined
```

This is the Schema file

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

let Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    guildID: String,
    muteRoleID: String,
    modLogChannel: String,
    joinRoleID: String,
    modRoleID: [String],
    adminRoleID: [String],
})

export = mongoose.model('config', Schema)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You dont need to use `.exec()` and using `?.` is to see the `lenght` *not very sure*:

Answer (score 0):

```
const configFiles = await ConfigSchema.findOne({
    guildID: message.guild.id
})//.exec();

console.log(configFiles.adminRoleID) //console.log this first
```

Then use `map` or `find` to get the specific role.

EDIT:

Since you mentioned that the expected output is `[ "Test" ]`, Then you can use `configFiles.adminRoleID.length`

Comment: I've tried that, and I need to have the ? because I'm using TypeScript. It just returns undefined.

Comment: Did you tried basing in [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html)? Looks like you need to use `interface` then `extend` the document. Not quite pretty sure, I didn't know that you're using `typescript` my bad.